# How to reuse value of element for checkpoint later in the automation test in Katalon Studio

Tags: mobile, automation, katalon-studio

I am new to automation with Katalon Studio and I am in learning curve.
I have a problem related to mobile app and I'll explain it with the example below.

Let say there is an app which has ability to share the posts and any user can like the posts as well.  When the post is liked by tapping on thumbs up icon it increases the like count. Icon and count are separate elements. Let's say

```
Icon  = android.widget.ImageView3 
count = android.widget.TextView5
```

There is a test scenario to test (automate): when clicked on like Icon count must be increased by 1.

To automate this my approach is as follows

1. get the count value before tapping on it (Before Value)
2. then tap on Icon
3. then get the count value again (After Value)
4. Check whether count is increased or not by comparing with before value after value.

I need to know How to do this using Katalon Studio all or one of following:

- Record and replay
- Manual method
- Scripting

Or Is there any approach other than my above explained approach?

Thanx in advance.